# In MPI, how do reduce and scan differ?

Tags: mpi

I am teaching myself MPI. I am reading Python documentation on reduce and scan:
http://documen.tician.de/boostmpi/reference.html#boostmpi.scan

Both reduce and scan seem to take some function (op) and use it to reduce values obtained from individual processes into a single value.

How do reduce and scan differ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A reduction means all processors get the same value while scan returns the partial operation results on each processor. For instance, if you had 10 processors and you were taking the sum of their rank, `MPI_Reduce` would give you the scalar 45 (0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9) on the root process only while `MPI_scan` would give you the scalar of the reduction up to the rank of the processor on each processor. So processor 0 would get 0, processor 1 would get 1, processor 2 would get 3, and so on. Processor 9 would get 45.

In other words, if you were to make a list of all processors values found from `MPI_Scan` it would be:

```
[0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45]
```

with the scan result coming from `[0, 0+1, 0+1+2, 0+1+2+3, ..., 0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9]`

In Python, the list of results from `MPI_Reduce` would be (assuming processor 0 is the root):

```
[45, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

while other languages the `recvbuf` would have undefined data in it on all processors other than the root.

Comment: Thanks, but don't all reduces and scans have a root process? Isn't the result the same in the end in terms of what the root process receives (45)?

Comment: I just corrected the answer. Scan does not have a root process, all processors get some data (the partial reduction). Reduce only puts the answer on the root processor. The original answer was thinking of `MPI_Allreduce` which would put 45 on every processor.