# MPI Scan reversed

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, integration, reverse

I am using mpi_scan ([In MPI, how do reduce and scan differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966446/in-mpi-how-do-reduce-and-scan-differ)) to make a summation, in order for each process to have the partial sum.

However, it appears to me that using mpi_scan, the summation is done starting from the process at rank 0, and going on towards rank N. Is there a funcion that makes the reverse operation? I.e., from rank N to 0?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is no reverse scane, but I'd make a `MPI_Comm_split` communicator that reverses the process order: use one color, and let the key be `size-rank`. Then run the normal scan.